# Vim. Open file (under cursor), path starting with @/

Tags: webpack, vim

How to go to a file with a path like '@/components/foo.bar'?

I try settings in .vimrc like this, but it doesn’t help:

```
set path +=/home/leadbro/Work/Projects/teletype/source/**
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^(@/)','','g')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The parentheses in your pattern are taken literally; I think these are meant to be a capturing group (`\(...\)`), but none is necessary for this substitution. Just drop 'em.
- The `@` character by default isn't included in file names; cp. [`:help 'isfname'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27isfname%27). Without it, Vim just grabs the `/components/foo.bar` part, and the substitution won't help. As the `@` character by itself stands for any alphabetical characters in the option, it needs to be added via the strange `@-@` notation.

```
set path+=/home/leadbro/Work/Projects/teletype/source/**
set includeexpr=substitute(v:fname,'^@/','','g')
set isfname+=@-@
```